# App-pools (w3p.exe's) seem to hang after file update or configuration change

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net, application-pools

I have the following problem:

After an file update or a configuration change to one of the sites running on the iis server i need to kill all w3p.exe's running on that server in order to let the website/app-pool start again.

I have 2 servers and both servers have the same behavior, also the normal recycles don't work until all existing w3p.exe's (that not have been killed since the update)

the websites/app-pools start (i can see the w3p.exe in the task manager) but the sites don't actually start until i've killed the w3p.exe's.

At the moment i've killed the last active w3p.exe all sites start their warmup.

Has anyone encountered this before? it keeps me from using continuous integration since i have to manually kill all the app-pools after a release

**update 1**

The pools aren't in use at the moment of the recycle, i tried this by making them only accessible from the local machine which made sure i knew all the connections running on the pools

The pools do start after i killed all w3p.exe's or restarted the iis service, but after an file change or configuration change pools are not able to start after their recycle, they keep at 0 cpu until all pools have been killed.

The servers are running Windows server 2012 with the latest updates (although i have this problem for quite a while now, so it has been doing this before the latest updates too)

Comment: Are they in use?  It might be draining connections.  Might want to ask about integrations on SI.

Comment: They aren't actively used at that moment, some don't have been called since the start. (i tested that in specific by creating an app pool that can only be called locally) its just that all w3p.exe's that are running on the moment of the update need to be killed before any w3p/exe can start its init

Comment: And should't different app-pools be fully separated from each other?
One app-pool cant affect an other one, right?

Comment: I would think that as long as the applications are different and the accounts are different, then yes, so long as no app pools call each other.  One troubling item is that you mention that the pools can't recycle. Can they recycle after you've (effectively) restarted IIS?

Comment: Nope they don't interact with each other, and they don't have any shared files

Comment: if you make a plain website HTML will that app pool recycle? Which OS is this on?

Comment: No also plain html sites in a seperate pool wont start after an update until all pools have been killed, and the os is windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

if a plain html site won't recycle then there are serious configuration issues with IIS.  Try building a new server and start adding your apps/changes 1 by 1 until it breaks again to isolate the configuration issue.  The fact that you've had this issue for a while means we have to start from scratch to isolate the problem.